# Browne & Park Grassman Algebra package?

Tags: packages

This year's Wolfram Innovator awards honored David Park Jr. and mentioned work on a Grassman Algebra & calculus package. This led me to find the Grassman Algebra book by John Browne https://grassmannalgebra.com/index.htm -- I went ahead and bought a copy but I've been trying unsuccessfully to get a copy of the software so I thought I would ask here. Does anyone know how I might get access to the software to accompany the book?

Comment: I do not know where to get the package to this book. But perhaps the following package will help: https://sites.google.com/site/grassmannalgebra/thegrassmannalgebrapackage. Packages using Grassman algebra dedicated to algebraic geometry are e.g.: CLUCalc and CLUViz

Comment: Thank you! That does seem to be a predecessor to the book's version so I'm sure that will still be helpful.

Comment: You could try to contact David Park by email: djmpark@comcast.net

Comment: There is another mail address at Davids user [profile](https://community.wolfram.com/web/djmpark) on Wolfram Community

Answer (score 5):

In case OP (or anyone else) is still looking, David has posted a link to download the newer [GrassmanCalculus package](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qqj5idyl8vxh80y/AADJ_ANZQni3ww6EKafKSNc3a?dl=0) (which I believe builds on and subsumes Browne’s original GrassmannAlgebra package) on his [user profile](https://community.wolfram.com/web/djmpark). I’m guessing it must’ve been added after @hmilton’s last comment above. The paclet was most recently updated in April 2023, for Mathematica 13.0+.

The included installation info [txt file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/82x9mqrjmrfpxm3k6g8iv/InstallingGrassmannCalculus.txt?rlkey=i2h88aiuyi15rtubvk48dmvjy&dl=1) mentions:

> John's Volume 1 Foundations Book (along with some early draft chapters for Volume 2) is contained in the paclet.

and

> Unfortunately John Browne (1942-2021) is no longer with us but David Park can answer many questions on the Algebra.

John’s book is also available to read for free in its entirety on [Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Grassmann_Algebra_Volume_1_Foundations/IuYIAwAAQBAJ?hl=en) (along with another of his works).